# What is the least costly way to finish the inside walls to a 16 X20 garage

Tags: garage, finish

How is the most cost effective way to finish out the walls to a garage?

Comment: Attached or detached?  If detached, how close is it to the home?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "most cost effective". Hiring the work out and then not paying might be very cost effective. Leaving the walls unfinished might prove to be more cost effective than having the walls finished if the metric is return on investment at the time of resale.

Comment: Questions related to product pricing are off topic. For more details, see [what topics can I ask about here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

Drywall is typically used when a finished garage is called out on the plans. Even though drywall prices have risen quite a bit in recent times it is probably still the most cost effective material to close up open studs and ceiling joists in a garage.